# Populate comboBox from listBox values in C#

Tags: c#, combobox, listbox, listboxitem

I can't solve this problem. I need to populate `comboBox` items from values in `listBox` (Windows Form in C#).
Every time I add values ​​in `listbox`, `combobox` automatically has to be populated.

Thanks in advance.

this is code, but now working

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Please update your post with a sample of your code.  Specifically the part of code that is not working.

Comment: Please share your codes.

Comment: You can do this by creating a BindingList and assigning the source of the ComboBox to that BindingList let me know if you would like a working example

Comment: thanks, I need please a working example, thanks in advance

Comment: vincetlerry how are you populating the combobox initially..?

Comment: initially I populate comboBox in this way:

comboBox1.Items.Add("Hello");
comboBox1.Items.Add("Good Morning");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private BindingList<string> bindingList;

List<string> stringList = new List<string();
//populate the list any way you want for example
stringList.Add("Hello");
stringList.Add("Good Morning");

bindingList = new BindingList<string>(stringList);
this.comboBox1.DataSource = bindingList;
this.listBox1.DataSource = bindingList;
```

I would suggest loading the strngList variable using a loop or if the data is coming from a database load the fields that way then Bind to the ComboBox.

Comment: Sorry my incompetence DJ Kraze, but I dont understand how use values from listBox, because comboBox has to be populate from ListBox. thanks for your patience

Comment: @vincentlerry if you bind both of them to the same BindingList and the BindingList uses 'stringList' all you have to do is add or remove items from stringList and both the listBox and comboBox will stay in sync. You do add/remove items from the listBox directly, you do it via 'stringList' Keeping both controls in sync is what you want right?